# Use one domain with two nameservers that serve different records

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver, dns-servers

I ask this knowing the answer is 99% likely to be "no, that's not the point of NS at all," but hey, I'm not a true webmaster so thought I'd check.

I would like to set up one root domain with two nameservers (not for redundancy) so that I can manage different sets of subdomains in two different places. Example:

**Domain:** example.com

**Location 1 (DNS registrar)**

```
A example.com 0.0.0.0
A a.example.com 0.0.0.1
A b.example.com 0.0.0.2
etc...
```

**Location 2 (NAS)**

```
A x.example.com 0.0.0.3
A y.example.com 0.0.0.4
A z.example.com 0.0.0.5
etc...
```

Is this possible? If so, how? Or have I lost all semblance of sanity?

---

**Why I want to do this**

I have some various hosted websites and I manage their DNS through my registrar. I recently set up a NAS at home and love it, and have bunches of personal services running on it and will definitely add more.

I would love to be able to manage the DNS for the services running on the NAS *from* the NAS, it would just be more convenient... but I'd rather not do it on a double subdomain, e.g. if an `NS` record for `n.example.com` is pointed at my local NAS' DNS server, then all the domains I create on the NAS will be `a.n.example.com`, etc.

I don't want to just manage all the DNS on my NAS, as I'm not confident in my ISP.

Comment: What you have wont work without breaking DNS badly. I cant work out a way of doing what you are trying with the restrictions stated/implied in your post.

Comment: @Steve sounds like an answer to me

Comment: What does the NAS have to do with the ISP you don't trust ?

Comment: @Steve I'm a fiddler, I'm constantly playing around with little services on new subdomains, shutting down old ones, that kind of thing. Thanks for the answer, I've upvoted your comment at least and if you submit as an answer I'll select it.

Comment: @Kate serving all my DNS from home the worries are having internet go down and causing issues, and not having the same level of trust/reputation as an actual registrar. Not sure if those are actually valid reasons not to host all my own DNS locally. From what I've read it does seem like it's frowned upon.

Comment: IP reputation does not matter here. It's true that a residential connection is not optimal for hosting services but can still be done for experimenting and nonprofessional needs.

Comment: Thanks @Kate, unfortunately for me I'm using this domain name for some more professional sites alongside my personal play. That said, you've inspired me to use a separate domain just for local DNS serving, experimentation, etc. Thanks all for your input!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "no" as you suspected.

But how often do you have to "manage DNS"? Mostly it is a set once and then rarely change it, surely that isn't a huge inconvenience to do at your registrar, you would have to log in and navigate to DNS on both.

If you really wanted to do it, you could set up CNAME records a.example.com -> a.n.example.com - do as many as you might need, doesn't matter if you don't use them.